# changing y scale when using fun.y ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scale

This an example of my data

```
library(ggplot)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Groups = factor(rep(1:10, each = 10)))
x <- sample(1:100, 50)
df[x, "Style"] <- "Lame"
df[-x, "Style"] <- "Cool"
df$Style <- factor(df$Style)

p <- ggplot() + stat_summary(data = df, aes(Groups, Style, fill = Style),
geom = "bar", fun.y = length, position=position_dodge())
```

(Sorry, this is my first question... I don't know how to present code snippets like head(df) or the actual plot in SO. Please run this code to understand my question.)

So the plot adequately presents the count of every 'Style' per 'Groups'. However, the y axis scale shows the levels of the factor variable 'Style'. Although values I am plotting are originally discrete, the count of every 'Cool' and 'Lame' per 'Groups' is continuous.

How do I change the 'y' scale of my barplot from discrete to continuous in ggplot2, in order to correspond to the count values and not the original factor levels???

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of `ggplot` grouping and the histogram to do this for you

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(Groups, fill=Style)) + geom_histogram(position=position_dodge())
```

Comment: Thank you so incredibly much!!! Unfortunately, I need 15 Reputation to give you an upvote... I am a noob. But please know how grateful I am.