# using fun.y in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am an absolute  beginner. So, I apologize for asking basic question. I am trying to plot the minimum value in my dataset. I looked at the following page ([changing y scale when using fun.y ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558633/changing-y-scale-when-using-fun-y-ggplot)) and didn't find the solution.

Here's the first code: this works well. It plotsa red dot at the mean.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(trans, cty)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun.y = "mean", colour = "red", size = 4)
```

This one doesn't work. Can someone please help me?

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(trans, cty)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun.ymin = min, colour = "red", size = 50)
```

I am not sure what's going on.

Comment: `fun.y = 'min'` should work, but also set the size to something less than 50 (like 2) or the points will be half as big as the plot.

Comment: Also, congratulations on having your first question be reproducible and relatively clear. In the future, do try to be more specific than "doesn't work"  - does it give an error or warning? If so, what does it say? Does it not produce a plot? Does it produce a plot that doesn't seem right? If so, what exactly seems wrong?

Comment: Awesome! That worked. I read ?stat_summary, and there the official guide uses "fun.ymin = min". Is that incorrect? Could you please explain this to me? I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `stat_summary`, what you plot depends on the `geom` you choose. You seem to want to plot points, so you chose `geom = 'point'`. A point only has a single y value, so only `fun.y` will be used by the summary.

There are other arguments, `fun.ymin` and `fun.ymax`. This isn't super clear in the documentation, but they are needed if you are using geoms that take additional aesthetics. For example, `geom = 'pointrange'` plots a point and a vertical bar with a `ymin` and a `ymax`:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(trans, cty)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(geom = 'pointrange', fun.ymin = min, fun.ymax = max, fun.y = mean, colour = "red", size = 1)
```

In this case, `ggplot` is coded in an adaptable way so that you can pass the name of a function as a character string, `fun.ymin = 'min'`, or you can pass the function directly, `fun.ymin = min`.